# find the value of $\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{\ldots}}}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving, continued-fractions

the question is to find the value of this ugly non-stopping fraction $$\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{\ldots}}}}$$.

I have totally no clue; thanks for the help! How am I suppose to solve this thing? This thing certainly looks ugly.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Are the terms in $\ldots$ repeating like $4 + 1/(\ldots)$?

Comment: Can you at least do a search here on MSE first before ... copy and pasting your question?  I'm sure (similar) questions has been asked numerous times already.

Comment: @user88786: Did you create five different accounts to ask five questions in a row? One account would work.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to give *some* idea of what the $\dots$ represent. I can't tell. Is it fours all the way down?

Answer (score 7):

Let $x$ be your continued fraction so that:

$$x = \cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cdots}}}.$$

Notice the repeating nature after a while in the continued fraction (this is *very* important). We want to make use of this. To do so let's invert both sides:

$$x^{-1} = 2 + \cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cdots}}}.$$

Or written a slightly different way..

$$x^{-1} - 2 = \cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cdots}}}.$$

We are now left with evaluating the continued fraction on the right. This is actually simpler than it looks because of the self-similar behavior.

Define the following:

$$y = \cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cdots}}}.$$

Then:

$$y^{-1} = 4 + \cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cdots}}}.$$

Or..

$$y^{-1} = 4 + y.$$

Can you solve this for $y$? Do you see how this solves the problem at hand?

Comment: @MJD Wow thanks for that. I didn't know that command existed.

Comment: Glad to be of service. [See also…](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5058/25554)

Comment: Also, $y=2+\frac1{2+y}$ work as well.